# GoogleMaps directions service using ionic-native

Tags: google-maps, ionic2, google-directions-api, ionic-native

I am using googleMaps with my ionic2 app. I am using ionic-native lib.I have implemented a lot of the business so far and now I am trying to find the route between two points using google directions service. But I can't find any sample or where I could start. Any ideas or sample is fully appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a suitable solution ?

Answer (score 6):

Cordova has not implemented yet Directions-Service, so is not available for easy use in Ionic.

Here is an example how to use it in other way:

Open and edit 'src/index.html' then add this script reference before the closing of the body tag.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
```

I assume that you know how to create YOUR-API-KEY from the google API console.

Next, open and edit 'src/pages/home/home.html' then replace all tags inside 'ion-content' with this lines of tags.

```
<ion-content>
  <div id="floating-panel">
    <b>Start: </b>
    <select [(ngModel)]="start" id="start" (change)="calculateAndDisplayRoute()">
      <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
      <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
      <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
      <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
      <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
      <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
      <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
      <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
      <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
      <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
      <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
      <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
    </select><br>
    <b>End: </b>
    <select [(ngModel)]="end" id="end" (change)="calculateAndDisplayRoute()">
      <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
      <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
      <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
      <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
      <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
      <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
      <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
      <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
      <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
      <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
      <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
      <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div #map id="map"></div>
</ion-content>
```

Open and edit 'src/pages/home/home.ts' then replace all codes with this codes.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

declare var google;

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  @ViewChild('map') mapElement: ElementRef;
  map: any;
  start = 'chicago, il';
  end = 'chicago, il';
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.initMap();
  }

  initMap() {
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, {
      zoom: 7,
      center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
    });

    this.directionsDisplay.setMap(this.map);
  }

  calculateAndDisplayRoute() {
    this.directionsService.route({
      origin: this.start,
      destination: this.end,
      travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }, (response, status) => {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        this.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

[Reference Link](https://www.djamware.com/post/58f4da2080aca7414e78a638/step-by-step-tutorial-of-ionic-3-angular-4-and-google-maps-directions-service?utm_campaign=shareaholic&utm_medium=google_plus&utm_source=socialnetwork)

Comment: You can have unlimited API calls using native but JS allow only 2500 per day

Comment: @Omkar Frozen :sir  i have used above plugin but i got status will be 'Not found' why get this error do you have any idea sir?

Comment: how are you installing it? looks like you are missing ionic wrapper